# How to aggregate and plot data of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, bar-chart

My raw data

```
head(predictionDB)
  Helpful X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22
1       1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
2       0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
```

I have aggregated them using the following code:

```
plotDB <- aggregate(predictionDB, 
                    list(predictionDB$Helpful), 
                    mean)
```

This is the output data

```
> plotDB
  Group.1 Helpful        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6        X7        X8        X9       X10       X11      X12       X13       X14       X15       X16       X17       X18       X19       X20       X21       X22
1       0       0 0.1666192 0.1857021 0.2418114 0.2258616 0.1774423 0.1874110 0.2603247 0.1777271 0.1407007 0.1540872 0.1794361 0.174879 0.1859869 0.3691256 0.2574765 0.1569353 0.2455141 0.1726004 0.1572202 0.2016520 0.2267160 0.1911136
2       1       1 0.2896282 0.3180039 0.2896282 0.3072407 0.2666341 0.3228963 0.2793542 0.2818004 0.2504892 0.2607632 0.2588063 0.316047 0.3317025 0.2896282 0.3003914 0.2656556 0.3047945 0.2999022 0.3126223 0.3131115 0.2813112 0.3131115
```

Now I want to create a plot which includes the variables on the x axis in order to compare the means of all variables X for Helpful = 0 and Helpful = 1.

Using the following code gives me the plot that I need for both helpful classes with each variable, but there are not labels on the x-axis at all.

Problems :

- the y axis just goes up to 0.30 while there are some cases above it
- there's no label for the helpful classes (1,0) under the bars

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(plotDB[,3:nTopicsLDA])), 
        beside=TRUE)
```

where nTopicsLDA is a numeric variable, in this case 22.

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is nTopicsLDA ? and could you give all your dataset or a minimum example which make us able to reproduce the bad barplot you give. What are the type of your data ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `barplot` uses the underlying matrix's column headers for x-axis labels, your plot renders no x-axis labels since `t(as.matrix(...))` returns an empty `colnames`:

```
colnames(t(as.matrix(plotDB[,3:nTopicsLDA])))
# NULL
```

Consider reshaping your wide data frame into long format (usually the preferred structure for most data analytics operations including plotting) and build plot matrix with `tapply`:

```
# RESHAPE WIDE TO LONG
predictionDB_long <- reshape(predictionDB, idvar = "Helpful",
                             varying=names(predictionDB)[-1], v.names="Value",
                             times = names(predictionDB)[-1], timevar = "X",
                             new.row.names = 1:1E5, direction="long")

# TAPPLY MEAN CALL ON TWO GROUPINGS FOR 2-D MATRIX
plot_mat <- with(predictionDB_long, tapply(Value, list(X, Helpful), mean))

# RE-ORDER COLUMNS
plot_mat <- plot_mat[paste0("X", 1:nTopicsLDA),]
```

Doing so, the `colnames` of *plot_mat* becomes the x-axis labels. However, only one x-axis labels render by default:

```
# BAR PLOT WITH ONE AXIS
barplot(plot_mat, ylim=c(0, 0.6), beside=TRUE, cex.names=0.75,
        main = "Mean Helpful Bar Plot")
```

[image: Bar Plot with One Axis]

For two axes, you need a customized solution such as calling `axis()` adjusting horizontal and padding parameters accordingly by font sizes. See how `row.names` had to be integrated. Do note the accommodation of middle space between the binary sets of *Helpful* bars:

```
# BAR PLOT WITH TWO AXES
barplot(plot_mat, ylim=c(0, 0.6), beside=TRUE, cex.names=0.75,
        main = "Mean Helpful Bar Plot")

axis(1, at=1:(nTopicsLDA*2 + 2), hadj=-0.5, padj=-2,
     labels=c(row.names(plot_mat), "", row.names(plot_mat), ""), cex.axis=0.5)
```

[image: Bar Plot with Two Axes]

---

**Data**

```
set.seed(9132019)
predictionDB <- data.frame(Helpful = sample(c(0, 1), 500, replace=TRUE),
                           replicate(22, sample(c(0, 1), 500, replace=TRUE))
)
nTopicsLDA <- ncol(predictionDB) - 1
```